# Attaching records to a Laravel hasManyThrough relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

A simple and straight one:

How can I **attach or detach new records** when using a Laravel *hasManyThrough* relation *the Laravel way*?
Model retrieving is obvious, from the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

**EDIT**: In other words, is there a *Laravelish way* of doing the following smarter (model names taken from docs)?

```
$user = $country->users()->first;
$post->user_id = $user->id;
$post->save();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't really have other ways to update the relation for a HasManyThrough as it's an attribute in the model... Simply retrieve the post you want to update, and the user to assign it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hasManyThrough()` requires an existing intermediate relationship.  In the docs example, `User` is the intermediate relationship.  Directly attaching a `Post` to a `Country` is not possible because it doesn't know which `User` owns it.  You need to first attach it to the `User`.

Answer (score 4):

https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasManyThrough.html

Yes, but you have to specify all the params.

```php
firstOrNew 
// (Doesn't persist to DB, you have to manually call the save method later on the created model)
updateOrCreate 
// (Persists to DB)
rawUpdate 
// (Persists to DB, not recommended)
```

`push` is supposed to work too, according to the docs.

On a 1:M relationship, there's the `save` method available out of the box. That's because the only field Laravel has to **fill in** is the foreign key.

For example, Let's say you've got a `Parent` and `Child` models. When you call

```php
$parent->children()->save(new Child(...));
```

Laravel [fills in the foreign key and persists the model](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.html#method_setForeignAttributesForCreate)

If we had a `GrandParent` model as well, and we tried to save a child through a HasManyThrough relationship:

```
$grandparent->grandchildren()
```

Laravel would not only have to fill in for the Parent foreign key, but maybe even create a new Parent model as well since we're not sure it exists. That's why there's not a `save` method implemented.

Therefore, you can make something like

```php
$grandparent->grandchildren()->firstOrNew(['parent_id' => $parent_id])->save();
// Or
$grandparent->grandchildren()->updateOrCreate(['parent_id' => $parent_id]);
```

You need a valid key too or else you'll get a SQL constraint violation.

Comment: ‘Push’ didn’t work for me in this case in laravel 5.8, which led me to looking for the reason and this answer.